# ytdl-core issue getInfo giving me 'Invalid or unexpected token' error

Tags: node.js, ytdl

i'm trying to get video info using ytdl- core, one day ego everythig is working properly but from today i'm getting error.
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at new Script (node:vm:94:7)
at exports.decipherFormats (E:\Projects files\Node JS\YT Video MP4\YTtomp4\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\sig.js:116:51)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async exports.getInfo (E:\Projects files\Node JS\YT Video MP4\YTtomp4\node_modules\ytdl-core\lib\info.js:401:17)

my - Node.js v 18.18.2
ytdl core version - 4.11.5